# what is the difference between array<string> and Array<String> in Spark?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I used this code to aggragate the grouped data:

```
val result=union_df.orderBy(desc("timestamp")).groupBy("id").agg(collect_set("region") as "region")
```

Then I got the datatype:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, region: array<string>]
```

What is the different between `array<string>` and `Array<String>`? How do I iterate over `array<string>` in map function (there is no `getArray` function for Row)?

Comment: `array<string>` and `string` are not Scala types, they are just results of `toString` call on a `DataType` which is called by `toString` on `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `getSeq()` function that returns a array or you can use `getAs` method by `getAs[Array[String]]()` or `getAs[Seq[String]]()`

`array<string>` is `scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]]` which is same as a `Array<String>` with a wrapper on it which is used inside a `Row`.